# I accidentally deleted nano on my Mac OS, how can I restore it?

Tags: macos, reinstall, xcode, homebrew

I had to copy the binary version of nano to my dev server -- and I accidentally deleted my local copy of nano in the process.

I tried to recompile nano from the original site, but now whenever I'm using git and various other tools that load up nano it frequently crashes and has segment faults.

I come from the Windows world, so typically I would just install uninstall.

I'm not sure how to properly uninstall the compiled version of crashing nano that I have here, to get the original one that was on the machine with XCode/Mavericks without breaking my work flow and a bunch of other tools I've install with homebrew in the process.

Answer (score 2):

You can download an OS X installer from App Store and use [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com):

[image]

Some other binaries like vi are included on the recovery partition but nano is not. You can see for yourself by running `diskutil mount Recovery\ HD;hdiutil mount /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/BaseSystem.dmg;ls /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/usr/bin`.

Answer (score -1):

You can install the latest version with homebrew.
Simply run `brew tap homebrew/dupes`, followed by `brew install nano`.